# Stimulsoft fields with the same data

Tags: c#, stimulsoft

I´m making a program to generate the report through code.

First I go through the datagrid to remove the empty columns and the result of this operation is sent to the class to generate the report.
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
dt = DgvNomina.DataSource as DataTable;

```
            foreach (DataRow r in dt.Rows)
            {
                for(int i = dt.Columns.Count - 1; i >= 0; i--)
                {
                    if (r[dt.Columns[i]].ToString() == string.Empty)
                    {
                        dt.Columns.RemoveAt(i);
                    }
                }
            }

            Imprimir_Nomina(dt);//clase para generar reporte
```

Then I use this code to make the report.
The code comes on the page, I just adapt it to my needs.

```
private void Imprimir_Nomina(DataTable table)
    {
        try
        {
            SplashScreenManager.ShowDefaultWaitForm("Cargando Reporte...", "Por Favor Espere.");
            Reportes rep = new Reportes() { Nombre = "Reporte Nómina" }.GetbyName();//cargarmos el reporte

            StiReport report = new StiReport();
            report.LoadFromString(rep.Fichero);
            report.ReportName = rep.Nombre;

            DataView dv = new DataView(table);

            report.ScriptLanguage = StiReportLanguageType.CSharp;

            //añadimos los datos y variables
            report.RegData("GalaxySoft", dv);
            report.Dictionary.Variables.Add(new StiVariable("Titulo", ElcbDepartamentos.Text));
            report.Dictionary.Variables.Add(new StiVariable("FechaInicio", "De " + FI.ToLongDateString()));
            report.Dictionary.Variables.Add(new StiVariable("FechaFin", " A " + FF.ToLongDateString()));
            report.Dictionary.Synchronize();

            //establecemos la configuración de la hoja del reporte
            StiPage page = report.Pages.Items[0];
            page.PaperSize = PaperKind.Legal;
            page.Orientation = StiPageOrientation.Landscape;

            //creamos la banda de encabezado
            StiHeaderBand header = new StiHeaderBand();
            header.Height = 0.8f;
            header.Name = "Encabezado";
            page.Components.Add(header);

            //creamos el databand
            StiDataBand data = new StiDataBand();
            data.DataSourceName = "Nomina" + dv.Table.TableName;
            data.Height = 0.5f;
            data.Name = "Contenido";
            page.Components.Add(data);

            //creamos los textos de la tabla
            Double pos = 0;
            Double colW = 0;
            int nameIndex = 1;
            StiText headerText;
            StiText dataText;
            StiCondition condition;

            foreach (DataColumn col in dv.Table.Columns)
            {
                switch (col.Caption)
                {
                    case "ID":
                        //texto de encabezado
                        headerText = new StiText(new RectangleD(pos, 0, colW = 2, 0.5f));
                        headerText.Font = new Font("Arial", 8, FontStyle.Bold);
                        headerText.HorAlignment = StiTextHorAlignment.Center;
                        headerText.VertAlignment = StiVertAlignment.Center;
                        headerText.WordWrap = true;
                        headerText.Text.Value = col.Caption;
                        headerText.Name = "HeaderText" + nameIndex.ToString();
                        headerText.Brush = new StiSolidBrush(Color.LightGray);
                        headerText.Height = 0.8;
                        headerText.Border.Side = StiBorderSides.Bottom;
                        header.Components.Add(headerText);

                        //texto fila
                        dataText = new StiText(new RectangleD(pos, 0, colW = 2, 0.5f));
                        dataText.Font = new Font("Arial", 8);
                        dataText.HorAlignment = StiTextHorAlignment.Center;
                        dataText.VertAlignment = StiVertAlignment.Center;
                        dataText.Text.Value = "{view" + dv.Table.TableName + "." + Stimulsoft.Report.CodeDom.StiCodeDomSerializator.ReplaceSymbols(col.ColumnName) + "}";
                        dataText.Name = "DataText" + nameIndex.ToString();
                        dataText.Border.Side = StiBorderSides.Top;
                        dataText.Border.Side = StiBorderSides.Bottom;

                        //añadir resaltado
                        condition = new StiCondition();
                        condition.BackColor = Color.LightBlue;
                        condition.TextColor = Color.Black;
                        condition.Expression = "(Line & 1 == 1";
                        condition.Item = StiFilterItem.Expression;
                        dataText.Conditions.Add(condition);
                        data.Components.Add(dataText);
                        break;

                    case "Empleado":
                        //texto de encabezado
                        headerText = new StiText(new RectangleD(pos, 0, colW = 5, 0.5f));
                        headerText.Font = new Font("Arial", 8, FontStyle.Bold);
                        headerText.HorAlignment = StiTextHorAlignment.Center;
                        headerText.VertAlignment = StiVertAlignment.Center;
                        headerText.WordWrap = true;
                        headerText.Text.Value = col.Caption;
                        headerText.Name = "HeaderText" + nameIndex.ToString();
                        headerText.Brush = new StiSolidBrush(Color.LightGray);
                        headerText.Height = 0.8;
                        headerText.Border.Side = StiBorderSides.Bottom;
                        header.Components.Add(headerText);

                        //Texto de fila
                        dataText = new StiText(new RectangleD(pos, 0, colW = 5, 0.5f));
                        dataText.Font = new Font("Arial", 8);
                        dataText.HorAlignment = StiTextHorAlignment.Center;
                        dataText.VertAlignment = StiVertAlignment.Center;
                        dataText.Text.Value = "{view" + dv.Table.TableName + "." + Stimulsoft.Report.CodeDom.StiCodeDomSerializator.ReplaceSymbols(col.ColumnName) + "}";
                        dataText.Name = "DataText" + nameIndex.ToString();
                        dataText.Border.Side = StiBorderSides.Top;
                        dataText.Border.Side = StiBorderSides.Bottom;

                        //añadir resaltado
                        condition = new StiCondition();
                        condition.BackColor = Color.LightBlue;
                        condition.TextColor = Color.Black;
                        condition.Expression = "(Line & 1 == 1";
                        condition.Item = StiFilterItem.Expression;
                        dataText.Conditions.Add(condition);
                        data.Components.Add(dataText);
                        break;

                    case "Sueldo Base":
                        //texto de encabezado
                        headerText = new StiText(new RectangleD(pos, 0, colW = 2.5, 0.5f));
                        headerText.Font = new Font("Arial", 8, FontStyle.Bold);
                        headerText.HorAlignment = StiTextHorAlignment.Center;
                        headerText.VertAlignment = StiVertAlignment.Center;
                        headerText.WordWrap = true;
                        headerText.Text.Value = col.Caption;
                        headerText.Name = "HeaderText" + nameIndex.ToString();
                        headerText.Brush = new StiSolidBrush(Color.LightGray);
                        headerText.Height = 0.8;
                        headerText.Border.Side = StiBorderSides.Bottom;
                        header.Components.Add(headerText);

                        //texto de fila
                        dataText = new StiText(new RectangleD(pos, 0, colW = 2.5, 0.5f));
                        dataText.Font = new Font("Arial", 8);
                        dataText.HorAlignment = StiTextHorAlignment.Center;
                        dataText.VertAlignment = StiVertAlignment.Center;
                        dataText.Text.Value = "{view" + dv.Table.TableName + "." + Stimulsoft.Report.CodeDom.StiCodeDomSerializator.ReplaceSymbols(col.ColumnName) + "}";
                        dataText.Name = "DataText" + nameIndex.ToString();
                        dataText.Border.Side = StiBorderSides.Top;
                        dataText.Border.Side = StiBorderSides.Bottom;

                        //añadir resaltado
                        condition = new StiCondition();
                        condition.BackColor = Color.LightBlue;
                        condition.TextColor = Color.Black;
                        condition.Expression = "(Line & 1 == 1";
                        condition.Item = StiFilterItem.Expression;
                        dataText.Conditions.Add(condition);
                        data.Components.Add(dataText);
                        break;

                    default:
                        //texto de encabezado
                        headerText = new StiText(new RectangleD(pos, 0, colW = 2, 0.5f));
                        headerText.Font = new Font("Arial", 8, FontStyle.Bold);
                        headerText.HorAlignment = StiTextHorAlignment.Center;
                        headerText.VertAlignment = StiVertAlignment.Center;
                        headerText.WordWrap = true;
                        headerText.Text.Value = col.Caption;
                        headerText.Name = "HeaderText" + nameIndex.ToString();
                        headerText.Brush = new StiSolidBrush(Color.LightGray);
                        headerText.Height = 0.8;
                        headerText.Border.Side = StiBorderSides.Bottom;
                        header.Components.Add(headerText);

                        //texto fila
                        dataText = new StiText(new RectangleD(pos, 0, colW = 2, 0.5f));
                        dataText.Font = new Font("Arial", 8);
                        dataText.HorAlignment = StiTextHorAlignment.Center;
                        dataText.VertAlignment = StiVertAlignment.Center;
                        dataText.Text.Value = "{view" + dv.Table.TableName + "." + Stimulsoft.Report.CodeDom.StiCodeDomSerializator.ReplaceSymbols(col.ColumnName) + "}";
                        dataText.Name = "DataText" + nameIndex.ToString();
                        dataText.Border.Side = StiBorderSides.Top;
                        dataText.Border.Side = StiBorderSides.Bottom;

                        //añadir resaltado
                        condition = new StiCondition();
                        condition.BackColor = Color.LightBlue;
                        condition.TextColor = Color.Black;
                        condition.Expression = "(Line & 1 == 1";
                        condition.Item = StiFilterItem.Expression;
                        dataText.Conditions.Add(condition);
                        data.Components.Add(dataText);
                        break;
                }
                pos += colW;
                nameIndex++;
            }

            //Creamos el FooterBand
            StiFooterBand footer = new StiFooterBand();
            footer.Height = 0.5f;
            footer.Name = "FooterBand";
            page.Components.Add(footer);

            //Creamos el texto del FooterBand
            StiText textF = new StiText(new RectangleD(0, 0, page.Width, 0.5f));
            textF.Text.Value = "Total={Count()}";
            textF.HorAlignment = StiTextHorAlignment.Right;
            textF.Brush = new StiSolidBrush(Color.LightGray);
            footer.Components.Add(textF);

            report.Render(false);
            report.Show();

            SplashScreenManager.CloseDefaultWaitForm();
        }
        catch (SqlException ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("El reporte seleccionado no existe.\n" + ex.Message, Application.ProductName, MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
        }
    }
```

But when it gets to the 'report.Render (false);' part, it gives me the following error:

> System.Exception: 'c:\Users\SISTEMAS\AppData\Local\Temp\ia0gbyuy.0.cs(49,53) : error CS0102: The type 'Reports.Report' already contains a definition for 'Text2'c:\Users\SISTEMAS\AppData\Local\Temp\ia0gbyuy.0.cs(271,21) : error CS0111: Type 'Reports.Report' already defines a member called 'Text2__GetValue' with the same parameter types'

I've already searched but haven't found anything about the problem.

Answer (score 0):

use these codes below Instead of your code

```
StiReport report = new StiReport();
report.Load(Server.MapPath("../*yourfolder*/*mrt_report_name*.mrt"));
report.ReportName = "name your report";
report.Compile();
```

Comment: i can´t doing this. Cause I have save the report into the DataBase.

Comment: not problem only write report.Compile(); after report.ReportName = "name your report";